# Add sqllite column to an existing database or have database re-index upon delete

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

In my app I have an option for the user to completely reset the app (remove all data/preferences they have set) so what I did when they select reset is to do a delete all in the `ContentProvider`

for example

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(CalEvents.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

Doing this I thought the database now being cleared would start the id counter back at 1 but that is clearly not the case

The problem is that one of my tables used the database id `1-16` to look for data but when that table gets delete the next insert for that database would be `17-33` and that causes problems because I am looking for numbers 1-16 so it will never display data.

So part 1 of my question is, is it possible to get the table to re-index after I do a mass delete from it? I am guessing no but I do not know the answer.

If that is not possible how can I put out an update to the app where I can add a column to the table `without` deleting the data when it gets added? Currently I could increment the database version and the column would get added but it will delete all my data when the app updates and I do not want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SQLite's manual [here](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) you can re-index your auto id field by deleting its entry in the sqlite_sequence table like this:

```
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='<Your Table Name Here>';
```

I haven't done this myself but it should work.

**Edit**

It is not clear in the SQLite's manual that the entry of your table will be re-created whenever a new insertion happens, however it clearly states that you can update the sqlite_sequence. So if the deletion doesn't solve your problem you can try to update the index like this:

```
update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name='<Your Table Name Here>';
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried: 'database.execSQL("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name="+table+"");' and it didn't work

Comment: @LuisAlberto Sorry for the long delay but I just saw your comment, it seems that you are missing single quotes (') around your table name...